# Problems Installing perl-DBD-MySQL

Tags: mysql, yum

I'm having dependency problems installing perl-DBD-MySQL.
Server is running on Centos 6.4 and MySQL  5.5.31.

I ran this command

```
yum install perl-DBD-MySQL
```

Outputs:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security Loading mirror speeds from
cached hostfile  * base: mirror.nl.webzilla.com  * extras:
mirror.nl.webzilla.com  * updates: mirrors.supportex.net Setting up
Install Process Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 0:4.013-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package:
perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) Error: Package: perl-DBD-MySQL-4.013-3.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You
could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I noticed that I have `libmysqlclient.so.18`, and not `libmysqlclient.so.16` on the server.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a conflict in the instaled modules on your system. Please make sure your system is up-to-date first. Use these commands:

```
yum upgrade -y
yum install perl-DBD-MySQL
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Tchami this clearly does provide an answer (even though it's posed in the form of a request for clarification). I would say, however, that code only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such should be avoided.

Comment: I agree, but an explanation should be provided then, and the answer should be rephrased so it doesn't sound like a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your problem using the following command:

```
yum install perl-DBD-MySQL --enablerepo=*
```